# When adding values to a priority queue, when exactly are the values sorted?

Tags: java, sorting, comparator, priority-queue

Consider this pseudo-code:

```
PriorityQueue <Integer> pq = new PriorityQueue(new Comparator()
{
    public int compare(Object o1, Object o2) 
    {
         Integer e1 = (Integer)o1;
         Integer e2 = (Integer)o2;
         if (e1 > e2) {return -1;}
         if (e2 > e1) {return 1;}
         return 0;
     }
});

pq.add(4);
pq.add(7);
pq.add(5);
pq.add(2);
pq.add(9);
```

Now I'm wondering, when exactly during the run time does the queue run the compare() method? I assumed that it would follow this order:

i) First the numbers 4,7,5,2,9 are added to the queue in that order

ii) Then the priority queue uses the compare method to sort the values

In other words, the values are first inserted into the queue. Then they are sorted. Is this thinking correct? Or are the values sorted as they're being added to the queue?

Comment: Which language is this? What framework are you using?

Comment: Right, my bad. It's Java

Comment: The values must be sorted as they are added. Else, how should the queue know that you've finished adding elements?

Comment: What algorithm does the compare() method use exactly?

Comment: This is not defined. You should look into the source code of the `PriorityQueue` of your specific JDK version.

Comment: You could find out quite easily by adding a "`System.out.println("in compare()")`" line to your compare function

Answer (score 1):

PriorityQueues are not a simple sorted data structures like kind of sorted array.
PriorityQueue in java was implemented using priority heaps. You should learn how heaps work, but basically when you add a new element, maximum log(n) comparisons occurs. Comparing all elements with each other is not necessary. You can learn more about priority queues at https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Priority_queue

Comment: just another small question: what is the significance of the "return 1" and "return -1" in the compare() method? How does it determine the sorting?

Comment: @User95 What I interpret is like, it shows the difference between `e2` and `e1`.  So, for example say if `e2-e1 > 0` then it returns `1` else if `e2-e1<0` then returns `-1` esle returns `0`. Using this return values comparator sorts the values by swapping them.

Answer (score 1):

`PriorityQueue` class has a private field `Comparator` defined for the insertion order (`private final Comparator<? super E> comparator`)... so when you do:

```
PriorityQueue<Integer> pq = new PriorityQueue<>(foo);
```

where foo is an instance of  the comparator, that object will be initialized internally for that instance...

after the collection is created, you begin to add elements to it and here is where the magic happens.

just look inside the `PriorityQueue` class and you will find the method `siftUpUsingComparator`, that will be invoked, and uses the comparator you defined to verify the insertion order...

```
private void siftUpUsingComparator(int k, E x) {
    while (k > 0) {
        int parent = (k - 1) >>> 1;
        Object e = queue[parent];
        if (comparator.compare(x, (E) e) >= 0)
            break;
        queue[k] = e;
        k = parent;
    }
    queue[k] = x;
}
```

---

Offtopic:

you are using raw collections and that is bad, I sugest to adapt your code to something like:

```
Comparator<Integer> foo = (o1, o2) -> {
    Integer e1 = o1;
    Integer e2 = o2;
    if (e1 > e2) {
        return -1;
    }
    if (e2 > e1) {
        return 1;
    }
    return 0;
};
PriorityQueue<Integer> pq = new PriorityQueue<>(foo);

pq.add(4);
pq.add(7);
pq.add(5);
pq.add(2);
pq.add(9);
```

Comment: I took a look at the PriorityQueue class for Java: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/PriorityQueue.html

There doesn't seem to be any siftUpUsingComparator method

Comment: that is defined in an inner class, the ***private final class Itr implements Iterator<E> {***

Comment: The Comparator interface only cares about the sign of the return value, not its size. If we don't restrict return values to the set {-1, 0, 1}, the Comparator can be simplified even more: 

    `Comparator<Integer> foo = (o1, o2) -> Integer.compare(o1,o2);`